# Weird whitespace when I open a modal

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

There is this weird phenomena in the website that I am builiding that is keeping me for days.. (might be an easy yet strange one for others, so might as well give it a shot asking here).

Whenever I open a modal, in our navigation bar above, there would be a white space that may resemble a scrollbar for the page, yet I already made sure that overflow would be hidden. For more references here's an imgur post depicting it.

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il9wP.jpg)

Comment: pleash share your code

Comment: [Here's the code for it](https://codepen.io/drebap/pen/gqLLQq?editors=0100)

Comment: place the code in the question - not a commented link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this when clicking the modal.

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    display: none;
}
```

WHen closing the modal

```
display: initial
```

Please change the `body` to one of your child classes or id's containers.

Comment: Wow, it actually works. Thanks man. Mind explaining more how it happened? I am really confused as to why it keeps happening...